# Отключение spring-security-ldap в зависимости от профиля (отключить автоконфигурацию конкретных бинов)

Tags: spring-boot, ldap

Использую Spring Boot 2.7.11
Для авторизации пользователей через LDAP подключаю зависимость

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Но, при запуске с профилем "local" я использую авторизацию через БД, поэтому над конфигурационными классами
LdapAuthProvider, LdapConfig, ActiveDirectoryConfig
ставлю аннотацию
@Profile("!local")
В этом случае авторизация успешно проходит с помощью DbAuthProvider (который аннотирован @Profile("local").

Но!
При старте приложения в логе я вижу:

```
LDAP health check failed

org.springframework.ldap.CommunicationException: localhost:389; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: localhost:389
```

Можно ли как-то отключить автоматические попытки соединиться с сервером LDAP, в том случае, если в этом нет необходимости?